# Generalized eigenspace is finite

Tags: functional-analysis

Can anyone give a reference or a proof to show the generalized eigenspace corresponding to a non zero eigenvalue of a **compact operator defined on a Banach space** is finite dimensional? I already saw the answer when the operator defined on a Hilbert space.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you write that a generalized eigenspace is finite? There are at least a couple of things that could mean.

Comment: I'm sorry. It should be finite dimensional. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I learned this fact in the lecutre course "Functional Analysis 1", held at ETH Zürich in Fall 2015. You can find lecture notes [HERE](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/). These might turn into a book once. You will find Theorem 5.28, part (i) on page 226 helpful. The proof uses Fredholm Theory.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read it.